# Binding Virtual Functions in Parent Ctor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, bind, virtual-functions

Given this code:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo() : _myFunc( bind( &foo::testCall, this ) ){}
    virtual void testCall(){ cout << "foo" << endl; }
    void call(){ _myFunc(); }
private:
    function< void() > _myFunc;
};

class bar: public foo
{
public:
    virtual void testCall(){ cout << "bar" << endl; }
};

void main()
{
    bar test;
    test.call();
}
```

Why does it print "bar". I read [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors) and would have thought that "foo" would have been printed.

Comment: `bar.call()` doesn't seem right..

Comment: Note `main` must return `int`.

Comment: -1 for not posting [real code](http://ideone.com/QnCwnj)

Comment: What will really bake you noodle is the output when invoking `call()` from `foo`'s constructor in addition to your invoke from `test.call()` in `main()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Given the proper includes and using directive, and changing the return type, it [compiles and prints "bar"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46ef39dfc458b02d) with GCC 4.9. With Clang and libc++, it doesn't compile. Your example did not include `<functional>`.

Comment: @ πάνταῥεῖ and @ chris this compiles fine in VS2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the virtual function in the constructor you are binding to a member variable, and latter calling that variable (in this case dynamic dispatch is used).

The calling code should be: `test.call();`

More info [Boost::Bind and virtual function overloads: why do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282715/boostbind-and-virtual-function-overloads-why-do-they-work)

Comment: So I get what you are saying but in `foo`'s ctor I would have expected a hard coded address not one that would thunk.

Comment: Link added with more explaining about the behavior.

Comment: @JonathanMee its the address of a virtual member function, which is typically a base+offset into the virtual method table of the instance. By the time the object is fully constructed the member function address at that offset is `bar`'s