# Passing a virtual member method to thread()

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to pass a virtual method to the thread class' constructor (C++ thread).

After searching all over, I've only been able to pass a **non-virtual** member method.

My base class **A** has a *start* method as follows:

```
void A::start() {
    thread(&A::runnable,A()); // <--- What do I change here?
}
```

The function *runnable* is virtual and is also implemented in derived class **B**.
I override runnable in derived class **B**.

I then invoke *start* on **B**.

Obviously, and undesirably, the *start* function uses *runnable* implemented in **A** (instead of **B**) because it is explicitly defined in **A**::*start*.
Is there any way to let the *runnable* function be dynamically bound?

I thought of using templates and a couple of other creative solutions. (I eventually will implement *start* in B if there are no real solutions)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ using `std::bind` in this case would not change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Obviously, and undesirably, the start function uses runnable implemented in A (instead of B) because it is explicitly defined in A::start.

This could be obvious to you, but it is incorrect. When you create a thread you pass an unnamed temporary instance of class `A`, which obviously has type `A` so `A::runnable` would be always called, but you should pass `this`:

```
void A::start() {
    thread(&A::runnable,this); // <--- What do I change here?
}
```

Then proper virtual function would be called.
See [Boost::Bind and virtual function overloads: why do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282715/boostbind-and-virtual-function-overloads-why-do-they-work) for details why.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things to address.

First in `A::start()` you create an anonymous local thread object.  Unfortunately, this  object will be destructed as soon as you leave A::start().  This will trigger an abort.

**When you create a thread object you must always either `join()` it or `detach()` it before the object gets destructed.**

For the rest of the answer, I'll use a private thread t in A:

```
class A {
    ...
protected:
    thread t;       // default constructed thread object, i.e. without associated  thread of execution 
public:  
    ...
    ~A() {
        if (t.joinable())   // If thread active and not detached, be sure that it's joined before it is destructed !!
            t.join();
    }
....
};
```

Next, in your thread creation, you use `A()` as parameter.  This means that you will create a new anonymous A object and pass it as argument.  I guess it's not what you intend to do, so you use `this` instead.

Then, as was told by Slava,  when &A::runnable is used in combination with this,  it is the virtual function that is called. So start() should look like:

```
void start() {
    t = move (thread (&A::runnable, this )) ;  // Here I create an anonymous thread and move it to t.   
}
```

If your run this code, you'll notice that A::runnable() is called for class A objects and B::runnable() for class B objects.